# how to lock mysql myisam table with php

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone test mysql table lock using 2 php scripts. And mysql_query().

I tried for a day but i couldn't get table locked.

I want when one php script uses mysql table all other scripts wouldn't have access to it.

Can you provide 2 simple tested php scripts. And if you can show how they work online it would be perfect.

But it should be so that when first script works and locks mysql table other scripts should wait for its turn.

Like a queue only one script can access myisam mysql table at the same time. But please test your script before answer because i tried many things many advises and nothing works.

Comment: as seen in all your comments below under any answers people gave trying to help you, you are pretty much arrogant. Anyone trying to help someone like you is simply wasting their time.

Comment: Well I am happy that people are trying to help. But when I ask same question for 100 times and people still give that wrong answers how should I react? Or if i don't understand something. Try yourself what you advise. I simply cannot get it working. Reading documentation. And trying various things. It don't help. And people still I create 10 question on 10 forum. And people still give wrong advise. How can i react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't advise locking db tables explicitly if it is  not aimed to manage complex db logic at transaction level. The queries will still be sent out, but fail due to the lock or worse other transactions become deadlocked because of a lock acquired  at the wrong time.

As a consequence you are like to tank any semblance of performance in the application.

Edit:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/lock-tables.html

The documentation for mysql gives a detailed explanation of how the locks operate. Locks are acquired for the session using it, so if you want your session to not have access to certain tables and aliases, then you want to lock everything besides the tables you want to deny your session access to.

Not sure what locks you wish to test as an example.

```
       define("READ_LOCK", 0)
       define("WRITE_LOCK",1) 
       function lock_on_to_tables ($Tables, $lockType=0)
       {
         $sql = "LOCK TABLES "
        foreach ($Tables as $table)
           $sql .=  $table . " ,";
         $sql = substr($sql, 0, -1); // cut off last comma
         $sql .= $lockType ? " WRITE" : " READ;
         mysqli_query($sql); // or pdo or whatever is in use.  
       }
```

Unlock is just

```
  mysqli_query("UNLOCK TABLES") ;
```

Comment: Well again. no script no sense in words. I tried everything. If you know it try it yourself. And if it works show to everyone.

Comment: Well, again reading your answer for the second time. You have to understand. That I am not trying to find out if this method is good. I just trying to understand how it works. And it doesn't... Unless someone can show it. Because i cannot make a lock.

Comment: Added the basic script layout, note it acquires the lock for the session, so it doesn't lock your session out

Comment: Thank you for your work, at least you tried to provide some script though I don't understand if it works in the right way. I see only one script and it not tested but since I tested 10 scripts and no one works. Why do you think this one will work? but anyways thanks for providing a script at least not just words +1.

Answer (score 1):

You do not lock table with PHP. You do lock with mysql query. So basically you do a query with syntax as described [in mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) and that's it. For example:

```
mysqli_query("LOCK TABLES my_table READ");
```

And drop `mysql_` in favour of `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Comment: I don't see script. I see empty words)

Comment: Rly? why do I need stupid mysqli and slow PDO if i have simple tasks? How will it help. I tried PDO it doesn't change anything. I can execute any queries doesn't matter what locks i do

Comment: Also when you try to post something next time again. Read first that "READ" instruction doesn't even suppose to lock something for other scripts. It don't allow write to table only for current session. Other sessions can write and read and do everything.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of locks. One is what @WebnetMobile.com posted.

The other is called an advisory lock - you put up a flag, and everyone is required to check the flag before being allowed access. It's on you to check for the flag everywhere that needs it. But the advantage is you can exactly tune the locking to your needs.

Also, with InnoDB you can lock specific rows of the table, without locking the entire table.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: Thank you for telling me how many kinds of locks there are. But my question is scripts. If you think you know how to do it. Show everyone. + you give me link to innodb locking reads and I told i have MyISAM. Why do you think all scripts cannot access that one flag at the same time? It can and it does. And about locking rows its good but its only for innodb. And table lock is present in all mysql engines. But i don't see way to make it work. If you see. Test it.